# Is there a phrase for someone working on a long, tedious scholarly work?

Tags: expressions

I seem to recall a trope or literary character representing someone working on a dry, boring work of abstruse scholarship. I thought it might be *Middlemarch*'s Casaubon, but I don't think he quite fits the bill (he was actually something of a sham, not having the necessary German...)

The person I have in mind would be an ivory tower academic working on, for example, a ten-volume history of earthworms; not *entirely* pointless, but totally disconnected from any real-world relevance.

Comment: Perhaps a scholar?

Comment: I have in mind Gradgrind from Dickens' _Hard Times_. Not sure he quite fits your description though.

Answer (score 2):

A harmless drudge?

When, in 1755, Johnson published his [Dictionary of the English Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_English_Language), after seven years of solitary toil, he included this definition:

> Lexicographer: a writer of dictionaries; a harmless drudge that
>   busies himself in tracing the original and detailing the signification
>   of words

Comment: I like it, though it's not what I was thinking of...